# What is the difference between population and sample space?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_population),

> In statistics, a population is a set of similar items or events which is of interest for some question or experiment.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space),

> In probability theory, the sample space of an experiment or random
> trial is the set of all possible outcomes or results of that
> experiment.

**Question:** What is the difference between *population* and *sample space*? As far as I understand, they both imply the same thing, i.e., encompasse all possible outcomes/results/item.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1660038/505767

Comment: That answer provided throught the link, is not satisfying and I think it is wrong.

Comment: And also this one https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/175027